# Passing variable arguments in PHP to one array without array declaration

Tags: php, codeigniter

In PHP is there a way to pass variable arguments as a single array without requiring an array declaration?

I'm calling a function below like:

```
$this->layouts->add_include(array('css/style.css','css/internal.css'));
```

Is there any way in the function to make it accept multiple variable arguments without needing to declare the array like:

```
$this->layouts->add_include('css/style.css','css/internal.css');
```

If I do this above then I get the following error in my functions foreach loop using the second code sample:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

For reference the function is:

```
public function add_include($array)     
{
$asset_path = 'assets/';
  foreach($array as $array_item) {

    $this->CI->load->helper('url'); // Just in case!
    $this->includes[] = base_url() . $asset_path . $array_item;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func_get_args() can be used here

```
public function add_include()     
{
  $asset_path = 'assets/';
  foreach(func_get_args() as $array_item) {

    $this->CI->load->helper('url'); // Just in case!
    $this->includes[] = base_url() . $asset_path . $array_item;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant -- I knew about it, but didn't realize it'd work in this context. Thanks so much.